# SQL count many-to-many relations in common

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

i have a sql problem with this schemas :

`table user(id, name)
table page(id, name)
table page_user(id_page, id_user)`

one page can be liked by multiple users and one user can like multiple pages

i would like to select all users in my table with a column with the number of liked page in common with some fixe user
like :
`id_user | page_in_common_with_user_#id#_count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "liked page" refers to the `page_user` table, then you can use a self join:

```
select pu.id_user, count(pux.id_page) as PagesInCommonWithX
from page_user pu left join
     page_user pux
     on pu.id_page = pux.id_page and
        pux.id_user = $x
group by pu.id_user;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it easily by this query:

```
select id_user , count(id_page)
from user left outer join page_user on user.id = page_user.id_user
group by id_user
```

Comment: This just shows the number of pages that the user has liked.